# How to replace substrings in a column of file with strings from another file using awk?

Tags: awk

I got two files, and want to use awk to replace subtring in one column of file with the string in another file

```
f1:
1a1 aaa 777
3_3 ccc 6b6
3.3 ddd 666

f2:
b5g9aaa8y
5_6ccc9.

output:
1a1 b5g9aaa8y 777
3_3 5_6ccc9. 6b6
```

I think I can do this within two steps:

1. make a intersection dict FILE of substring and string
2. use awk(sub) to finish it

However, is there a one line awk command to check if substring in string and then do replacement?

#

Sorry, I should have explained it more clearly.

1. The string format and length in file2 are not fixed.
2. file1 and file2 do not have the same number of records. file2 is a subset of file1, only need to output the string in file2
3. assume there is not multiple hits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP has changed samples and added complete conditions now, so adding this solution.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;b[$2]=$3;next} {for(i in a){if(index($0,i)){print a[i],$0,b[i];delete a[i];break}}}'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1
  b[$2]=$3
  next
}
{
  for(i in a){
    if(index($0,i)){
      print a[i],$0,b[i]
      delete a[i]
      break;
    }
  }
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per @sjsam comment in case range for `substr` may vary then as per samples provided one could try following too. It considers that you want to have only alphabets as index and remove everything from line of Input_file2(which OP confirmed in comments too).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{val=$0;gsub(/[^[a-zA-Z]]*/,"");a[$0]=val;next} {$2=$2 in a?a[$2]:$2} 1'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[substr($0,3,3)]=$0;next} {$2=$2 in a?a[$2]:$2} 1' Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
111 33aaa8 777
333 56ccc9 666
```